# STS shows a false error in a Grails service

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

**The code listed here works, but** STS shows an annoying error: `Groovy: unable to resolve class Comentario`:

[image: printscreen with the error]

This is a extract of the Service code with the line of the error (`new Comentario(params).save()`)":

```
package alojamiento

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

class ComentarioJQGridService {

    static transactional = true

    @Transactional
    def cambiarComentario(params) { 

        Comentario.withTransaction { status ->
            new Comentario(params).save()
        }

    }
}
```

This is an extract of the domain class:

```
package alojamiento

class Comentario implements Serializable {
    Integer id
    String comentario
    ...
```

It looks similar to the official [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.2/guide/services.html#transactionsRollbackAndTheSession), so I think it is a STS issue. Why is it? How could I remove this error?

Comment: `grails-app/domain` is not present in the project's source path, try adding that.

Comment: I think it is in the Build Path: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3653993/domain%20src%20in%20java%20build%20path.png

Comment: Saw the snapshot. It only includes `*.java`. Either `include all` or add `*.groovy` in `included`. BTW you need not include `*.java`.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks. Specifically I did: right click to the project - properties - Java BuildPath. Look for: ProjectName/grails-app/domain - Included, then Edit, Add - **/*.groovy.